# Filter table renders in vue3 and quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have an aplication in vue3 and quasar, that renders a few tables according to an array I'm getting from an API. The number of tables and their content all come from this API. For each named that contains in the array it will render one table. Thing is, I have a dropdown with all the nameId's and when selected it send the id to the table. What I need to do (but am not being able to) is filter this tables. The default value of selectedName is null, and when null it should show all the tables and when I select a name in the dropdown, it should only show the table with that name. Both nameId and selectedId are numbers, here's the template of my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <template v-if="Number(props.selectedName) === null">
      <div v-for="(endpointData, nameId) in organizedData" :key="nameId">
        <q-table :rows="endpointData" :columns="getColumns(nameId)" row-key="EndpointId" />
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div v-for="(endpointData, nameId) in organizedData" :key="nameId">
        <q-table :rows="endpointData" :columns="getColumns(nameId)" row-key="EndpointId" />
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```